# error:cannot read property "props " of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am having a troubling error "cannot read property "props" of undefined" in reactjs sorry for noob questions can anyone help me with this??

app component

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  onSubmit(){
    console.log("something");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}></Form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

form component

```
export default function Form() {

   const {onSubmit}  = this.props;
   
    return (
        <div className="form">
            <input className="textbar" placeholder="Search for username" name="name"></input>
            <button className="button" onClick={()=>onSubmit} >Search</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

the error is in form component in 2nd line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `props` as the argument of the function, as such:

```
export default function Form(props) {

   const {onSubmit}  = props;
   
    return (
        <div className="form">
            <input className="textbar" placeholder="Search for username" name="name"></input>
            <button className="button" onClick={()=>onSubmit} >Search</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then you can simply destructure props by:

```
 const {onSubmit}  = props;
```

Comment: Do you have any typos? I think it should work.

Comment: 'props' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Does it say in which line?

Comment: Do your first line look like this?:
export default function Form(props) {

Comment: But if you didn't follow my advice, how did you expect it to work? I told you that you should define `props`.

Comment: calmdown and thanks i liked this method and i missed that line sorry

Comment: You are welcome. I think this is probably the best practice you could do for destructuring `props`. It's readable, maintainable and I think its good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Form is a functional component, you can not use `this` there.

change Form to this:

```
export default function Form({onSubmit}) {
    return (
        <div className="form">
            <input className="textbar" placeholder="Search for username" name="name"></input>
            <button className="button" onClick={onSubmit} >Search</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: this works but nothing is happening in cosole

Comment: You had an error on your onClick in the Form. Write like this: onClick={onSubmit}

Comment: thanks worked, but what if there are multiple function to pass

Comment: then you write `Form({onSubmit, otherFunction, andAnotherFunction})`. 
And just make sure that you pass down props that are named like that